# Multi commander: clean start-up state?

Tags: windows, file-management

I want [multi commander](http://multicommander.com/) to be in a clean state when I start it: only a single tab at each page.

Currently it has the same number of tabs there were when I closed it last time. I unchecked everything in "Save on exit" under Menu -> "Configuration" -> "Explorer Panel Settings". Still it opens the same number of tabs.

Answer (score 1):

This file manager can become very powerful if it will be properly supported.
It lacks a lot yet, but it's still the best option for professionals that need a good W7-compatible FM.
As for your question, all settings are stored under `username\appdata\roaming\MultiCommander\config`. There, you will find all custom configuration XMLs. Specifically, check `explorerpanel.xml` .
The save is done automatically, so your tabs are already saved. If you cannot change anything from configuration--core settings, deleting the XMLs I mentioned above will reset all it's settings to default.

Comment: Removing `explorerpanel.xml` removes configurations of the panel, but doesn't affect the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got some scripting skills, resetting the tabs is not that difficult.  You can write a script to reset the tabs and start Multi Commander.  Multi Commander saves the tab configuration in the Windows registry under its *Session History/AutoLoad* key.  See below:

[image]

The *AutoLoad* key will contain one or more **numbered** sub keys that represent the tabs that were open when you exited Multi Commander.  The sub keys are used to represent a Left or Right panel.  Removing the numbered keys will effectively remove the tab from the start up configuration.  Be careful of the numbering of the sub keys when removing tabs.  Multi Commander will display an empty panel (without a tab) if the sub keys are not sequential (ie. 0, 2, 3 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3).  You may wish to back up the MultiCommander key before removing the sub keys.

Comment: In order to modify registry one has to possess admin privileges. So fixing registry, and starting MC, will probably starts MC in admin mode. Which is a quite negative side effect.

Comment: You're not required to start MC in admin mode. I don't think there would be a problem with this approach. Not sure why you think running MC in admin is bad.

Comment: Running MC in admin mode is bad, because it requires user be fully aware of windows privilege system. If you have a script where some command needs admin privilege, that means you need to run the script as admin, which is same as running each command of the script as admin. So if you modify registry as admin, and you start MC in the same script, you will start it as admin.

Comment: I disagree with your reasoning.

Comment: I also disagree with that reasoning. Users and admins are split this way for a reason. If you are aware of risks and want to excessively protect your system, then you run it in user mode. But advanced file managers are for advanced users which will implicitly require complete unrestricted access to system.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I solved it:

```
MultiCommander.exe "c:\" "c:\"
```

opens clean state.

So one can add this to a shortcut:

[image]

and I also have it binded to Win-z in AutoHotKey:

```
; multi commander:
$#z::
IfWinExist Multi Commander v.*
{
  WinActivateBottom, Multi Commander v.*
}
Else
{
  Run "C:\Program Files\MultiCommander\MultiCommander.exe" "C:\" "C:\"
  WinActivateBottom, Multi Commander v.*
}
Return
```

This one opens Multi Commander if it is not running, otherwise it activates the its window.

Comment: Did you create a shortcut with this or a batch file? Can you explain how you use this code?

Comment: @MichaelFrank: see edit.